# Extract SQL result to CSV file Batch Job

Tags: mysql, batch-file, sqlcmd

I am writing a batch file to simply run the MySQL script and extract the result into a csv file. But nothing happens after running below batch script, anyone can help?

```
@echo off

set batch_name=Test
set today=%date:~10,4%%date:~4,2%%date:~7,2%
set today_day=%date:~7,2%
set today_year=%date:~10,4%
set today_month=%date:~4,2%
set log_file=C:\Temp_%today%.log

sqlcmd -S servername -d dbname -U username -P xxxxx -i C:\temp\Script.sql"
-o C:\Temp\Result.csv -w
```

Comment: `sqlcmd -S servername\instance_name...` also, what is in the `Script.sql`?

Comment: You write about a **MySQL**-script. But `sqlcmd` belongs to **MS SQL Server**. Please edit the question and correct it. Especially the tags. To see what your script does, run the command from the commandline-prompt instead of double clicking the batch-file. Then you should see an error message or why nothing happens.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
@echo off

set batch_name=Test
set today=%date:~10,4%%date:~4,2%%date:~7,2%
set today_day=%date:~7,2%
set today_year=%date:~10,4%
set today_month=%date:~4,2%
set log_file=C:\Temp_%today%.log

sqlcmd -S servername -d dbname -U username -P xxxxx -i C:\temp\Script.sql >> C:\Temp\Result.csv
```